# Having trouble understanding this command as part of a class

Tags: bash

```
for f in ${FILES}; do
    ((COUNT++))
    ln=$(wc -l ${f} | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
    echo "File number ${COUNT} (${f}) has ${ln} lines"
done
```

Comment: WHich line exactly you do not understand. Have you try to search in manual for `bash` about the meaning of commands?

Comment: What have you tried? What parts do you understand? Ho you know what it does? Have you got it to work?

Comment: Your teacher's use of capitals is at variance with the standards.

Comment: The readable text in the `echo` statement tells you exactly what each variable is intended to contain, which will show you the purpose of the individual constructs. Also, the necessity for the `cut` is very easily avoided.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in ${FILES}; do
    ((COUNT++))
    ln=$(wc -l ${f} | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
    echo "File number ${COUNT} (${f}) has ${ln} lines"
done
```

This is what a for loop looks like in bash.
For each item in `(list)` it assigns the value of the item to a variable called `f` and then executes the `[...]` section

```
for f in (list); do
 [...]
done
```

presumably, there's a string of filenames separated by spaces assigned to a variable called `FILES`

```
FILES="file1 file2 file3"
```

to access the contents of a variable, such as `FILES`, you must prepend a $ to the variable name.  You can write either `$FILES` or `${FILES}`

There's also a variable called "COUNT" assigned to 0 somewhere because the above code is trying to count the files listed

so we have...

```
FILES="file1 file2 file3"
COUNT=0
for f in ${FILES}; do
    [...]
done
```

every time f is assigned a new value, the [...] section runs

**what's in the [...] section?**
First we increment the COUNT variable.  In order to increment (add 1 to COUNT variable) using COUNT++, you're required to surround the arithmetic expression with (())

```
((COUNT++))
```

next we get the number of lines in each file.

```
ln=$(wc -l ${f} | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
```

lets deconstruct this.

1. **`wc -l ${f}`** we are using a program called `wc` (word count) with the `-l` (lines) option give us the line count of the file stored in `$f` whose output looks equivalent to this `57 file1` (line count then filename).
2. `wc -l ${f}`**`| cut -f 1 -d ' '`** since we only want the line count (57) and **not the filename** (file1), we take the output from `wc` i.e. `57 file1` and use it is as the input to the `cut` command to isolate `57`.  The `|` operator takes the output from one command and uses it as input to another. The `-d ' '` option specifies that we want to cut fields by spaces, and `-f 1` means output the first field, i.e. the `57`
3. **`$(`**`wc -l ${f} | cut -f 1 -d ' '`**`)`** Now our commands are outputting `57`.  In order to capture the output so it can be assigned to `ln` it must be wrapped in `$()`

last  output "File number 1 (file1) has  57 lines"

```
echo "File number ${COUNT} (${f}) has ${ln} lines"
```

Comment: With bash, an array `FILES=(file1 file2 file3)`, `${FILES}` will expand to `file1`. To expand it properly you'd want something like `"${FILES[@]}"`. In OPs case, `FILES` is likely just filenames delimited by whitespace.

Comment: @Torin you are correct, thank you